# Joining by multiple columns with incomplete overlap

Tags: r

There are many questions on joining and merging, but I'm unsure which option applies to my particular case.
I'm working with data acquired via a number of examinations (`exam`). The subjects received `examA` (with several values: `examA1` etc, summarised in `dfA`) and/or received `examB-D` (summarised in `dfB`) on certain dates. Here are some simplified samples:

```
> dfA
   subject date examA1 examA2 examA3
1 subject1 2012      1      1     13
2 subject1 2013      5      5     NA
3 subject2 2014      7      5      7
4 subject2 2016      2      1      1
5 subject3 2018      0     NA     NA
6 subject3 2020      3      5     NA
```

```
> dfB
   subject date examB examC examD
1 subject1 2012     2     1     0
2 subject1 2013     5     3    NA
3 subject2 2015     8     5     7
4 subject4 2016    NA     1    NA
```

Now I'd like to join the two by `subject`, but also match the `date`. Essentially, I need this to happen:

- If `examA` and `examB-D` were performed on the same date -> one row with all values.
- If only `examA` was performed on a particular date -> `date` is derived from `dfA`, columns for `examB-D` should be filled with `NA`.
- If only `examB-D` was performed on a particular date -> `date` is derived from `dfB`, columns for `examA` should be filled with `NA`.

Desired output:

```
> df.join
   subject date examA1 examA2 examA3 examB examC examD
1 subject1 2012      1      1     13     2     1     0
2 subject1 2013      5      5     NA     5     3    NA
3 subject2 2014      7      5      7    NA    NA    NA
4 subject2 2015     NA     NA     NA     8     5     7
5 subject2 2016      2      1      1    NA     1    NA
6 subject3 2018      0     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
7 subject3 2020      3      5     NA    NA    NA    NA
8 subject4 2016     NA     NA     NA    NA     1    NA
```

This code omits values from `dfB`:

```
df.join <- left_join(dfA, dfB, by = c("subject", "date"))
```

This code throws a many-to-many relationship warning and creates two date columns:

```
df.join <- left_join(dfA, dfB, by = c("subject"))
```

How do I adapt the join parameters to achieve my desired output? Thanks!

Code to create examples:

```
subject <- c("subject1", "subject1", "subject2", "subject2", "subject3", "subject3")
date <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2016, 2018, 2020)
examA1<- c(1, 5, 7, 2, 0, 3)
examA2 <- c(1, 5, 5, 1, NA, 5)
examA3 <- c(13, NA, 7, 1, NA, NA)
dfA <- data.frame(subject, date, examA1, examA2, examA3)

subject <- c("subject1", "subject1", "subject2", "subject4")
date <- c(2012, 2013, 2015, 2016)
examB<- c(2, 5, 8, NA)
examC <- c(1, 3, 5, 1)
examD <- c(0, NA, 7, NA)
dfB <- data.frame(subject, date, examB, examC, examD)

subject <- c("subject1", "subject1", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", "subject3", "subject3", "subject4")
date <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2018, 2020, 2016)
examA1<- c(1, 5, 7, NA, 2, 0, 3, NA)
examA2 <- c(1, 5, 5, NA, 1, NA, 5, NA)
examA3 <- c(13, NA, 7, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
examB<- c(2, 5, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA)
examC <- c(1, 3, NA, 5, 1, NA, NA, 1)
examD <- c(0, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA)
df.join <- data.frame(subject, date, examA1, examA2, examA3, examB, examC, examD)
```

Comment: What you are describing is a full join ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right ), though that row 5 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `full_join`

```
> full_join(dfA, dfB)
Joining with `by = join_by(subject, date)`
   subject date examA1 examA2 examA3 examB examC examD
1 subject1 2012      1      1     13     2     1     0
2 subject1 2013      5      5     NA     5     3    NA
3 subject2 2014      7      5      7    NA    NA    NA
4 subject2 2016      2      1      1    NA    NA    NA
5 subject3 2018      0     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
6 subject3 2020      3      5     NA    NA    NA    NA
7 subject2 2015     NA     NA     NA     8     5     7
8 subject4 2016     NA     NA     NA    NA     1    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge` with `all=TRUE`.

```
merge(dfA, dfB, all=TRUE)
#   subject date examA1 examA2 examA3 examB examC examD
#1 subject1 2012      1      1     13     2     1     0
#2 subject1 2013      5      5     NA     5     3    NA
#3 subject2 2014      7      5      7    NA    NA    NA
#4 subject2 2015     NA     NA     NA     8     5     7
#5 subject2 2016      2      1      1    NA    NA    NA
#6 subject3 2018      0     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
#7 subject3 2020      3      5     NA    NA    NA    NA
#8 subject4 2016     NA     NA     NA    NA     1    NA
```